# How can i solve these services errors on boot?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, services, cloud, certbot

I have an ubuntu 20.04 LTS server running nextcloud, when the server its booting some services failed on boot.

```
root@demg-srv:/etc/systemd/network# systemctl --failed
UNIT                                 LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
● cloud-config.service                 loaded failed failed Apply the settings specified in cloud-config
● cloud-final.service                  loaded failed failed Execute cloud user/final scripts
● cloud-init-local.service             loaded failed failed Initial cloud-init job (pre-networking)
● cloud-init.service                   loaded failed failed Initial cloud-init job (metadata service crawler)
● systemd-networkd-wait-online.service loaded failed failed Wait for Network to be Configured

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.
```

The status of each service show the same error that this one:


**cloud-config.service**

```
● cloud-config.service - Apply the settings specified in cloud-config
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cloud-config.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-04-14 14:04:58 UTC; 47min ago
    Process: 722 ExecStart=/usr/bin/cloud-init modules --mode=config (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 722 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

abr 14 14:04:58 demg-srv cloud-init[722]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2769, in _get_metadata
abr 14 14:04:58 demg-srv cloud-init[722]:     for line in self.get_metadata_lines(name):
abr 14 14:04:58 demg-srv cloud-init[722]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1433, in get_metadata_lines
abr 14 14:04:58 demg-srv cloud-init[722]:     return yield_lines(self.get_metadata(name))
abr 14 14:04:58 demg-srv cloud-init[722]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1425, in get_metadata
abr 14 14:04:58 demg-srv cloud-init[722]:     return value.decode('utf-8')
abr 14 14:04:58 demg-srv cloud-init[722]: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 217: invalid continuation byte in PKG-INFO file at path: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/acme-1.1.0.egg-info/PKG-INFO
abr 14 14:04:58 demg-srv systemd[1]: cloud-config.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
abr 14 14:04:58 demg-srv systemd[1]: cloud-config.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
abr 14 14:04:58 demg-srv systemd[1]: Failed to start Apply the settings specified in cloud-config.
```

**PKG-INFO**

```
MetadatA=Version: 2.1
Name: acme
Versyon: 1.1.0
Summary: ACME protoool implementatiof in python
Homa-page: hTTps://giuhub.com/letsencrypu/letsencrypt
Author:`Cgrtbot Project
Author-email: client-duv^@letsencrypt.org
Li�ense: Apache Licenwe 7.0
DescrittioN: UOKFOWN
Platform: UNKNOWN
Classifimr: Du7elopment Spatus :: 50- Producvion/StabLe
Classifie`: Intend%U Audiens%!:: Devgm^?xers
Classifier: Lisense :: OSI Approved :: Apaghu0Software License
Cmcssifier: Xrogrammino Languagf :: Python*Classifmer: Programming Lanfu�ge :: Pyvjon :: 2
classifierz!Programming Language�:: Pythkn :: 2.7^[Classifiar: Programming Language :: PytHon :: 3
Classifier: Programming$Langqage :: Pyth/n`^Z: 3.4
Classifier: Programming^@Languaoe :: Pyth^?j >: 3.5
K\assifier: Program�ing Language :: PythoN :: 3/v
Classifier: Psogramming Langwag%":: Python :: 3.7
Clc{sifier: ProgrammI.g Langu`ge :: Python >: 3.8
AlassIfier: Topia :: Ijvernet :: WWW/HTTP
c|assifier> ^Topic :: Security
Requires-Python: >=2.7, !=3.0.*$ !=3.1n*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*
prnvides-Extra: dev
ProvidEs-Extra2 docs
```

How can i solve eachone?

Comment: First, don't post pictures of text, especially dark red text on black background. To find out why they failed, get more info with `systemctl status SERVICENAME` and `journalctl -u SERVICENAME`.

Comment: @berndbausch , i edited the post, thanks to your help

Comment: cloud-config chokes on an "invalid continuation byte in PKG-INFO file at path:". The path is not shown because the terminal window is not wide enough. Press the arrow-right key to see it, or type `-S` followed by ENTER. I think it's crucial to know that path.

Comment: You PKG-INFO file looks incorrect. Did something go wrong during installation?

Comment: No, I think an update could have caused it, since certbot has been installed since June 2020, and it did not have this problem.